# a conflict between woocommerce price filter widget and materialize slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a woocommerce shop page with a price slider, and i have a materialize slider. there is a conflict between them that i do not know how to fix.
if i remove the price filter widget the materialize slider works just like it works in other pages.
but once the price filter widget is there, the materialize slider javascript doesn't work.
so i looked at the html and it seem that the price filter widget inject css classes and a span element. 
this is the materialize slider html when the price widget is removed, this works:
[image]

this is the materialize slider with the price widget enabled:
[image]

and this is the woocommerce price filter widget html:
[image]

i have no idea why the there is a conflict and how to fix it.

best regards